# Get pointer to windowed pixels

Tags: c, winapi

I would like to have a pointer to client pixels of a windowed window in order to blit my own pixels. I do not want to use Gdi set pixel function. How shall I proceed ? I don't want to use directdraw.

EDIT: If someone wants a ready code template, check out here :
http://sol.gfxile.net/wintut/ch3.html

Comment: Use a third-party library for the drawing (which will any way use GDI or DirectDraw in the end)? In Windows you have two ways to natively draw: GDI (or the modern GDI+) or DirectDraw/DirectX. That's it. Although you *could* get a pointer to the actual data and write the individual pixels yourself, but that's *really* not something anyone sane would recommend (you'll spend more time implementing and fixing your drawing code than your real program).

Comment: Is this your window or are you trying to hack another process? If the former ye BitBlt in your paint handler.

Comment: Yes but how to retrieve that pointer using direct X or direct 2d, directDraw is deprecated.

Comment: David Heffernan,   It is my window, but bitblit need two HDC, I want to copy data from a personal RGBA pixel pointer like this one int* pixels;

Comment: Use BitBlt. Make a bitmap for your off screen pixels. Then blit that bitmap's DC to the paint DC. You don't get to design the system. You adhere to the interfaces provided by the system.

Comment: my bitmap will get modified every frame, the problem is more complicated than that

Comment: So modify the bitmap pixels every frame. You can access them directly. Perhaps you should study GDI a bit more.

Comment: For high performance you could go with [DirectComposition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh437371.aspx). However, *"the DirectComposition API is intended for experienced and highly-capable graphics developers who know C/C++, have a solid understanding of the Component Object Model (COM), and are familiar with Windows programming concepts."*, so this might not be for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GDI always hides the screen display behind an HDC so you are always going to need to use BitBlt with a source, and destination HDC to get content onto it.

However, as a compromise, I think you are looking for the method `CreateDIBSection` which will give you an area of memory you can directly manipulate, as well as an HBITMAP representing it that you can select into a source DC and thus blit to the display.